# Cassandra : There is no ring for the keyspace

Tags: cassandra, bigdata, cql

When I run the nodetool command it gives me the following exception in Cassandra. I am using cassandra version 1.2.1.

I have copied the data from my keyspace from my old Cassandra cluster to new Cassandra cluster and created a schema in my new cluster. I am able to get some information back, but when I am trying to create something it does create a new key but I am also getting the following exception. It is the same for `nodetool describering system`.

Could any one please let me know what is going wrong and where?

```
nodetool describering system_auth

Schema Version:67158f43-3871-3496-9ab4-4f73d0450575
TokenRange:
There is no ring for the keyspace: system_auth
java.io.IOException: There is no ring for the keyspace: system_auth
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.describeRingJMX(StorageService.java:1017)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:93)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:27)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:208)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:120)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:262)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1454)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:74)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1295)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1387)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:818)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor45.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:303)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1):

In version 1.2.1, `system_auth` was a plain system keyspace, so it didn't have any replication associated with it (and thus, no ring). The `system` system keyspace also has no ring associated with it.

In version 1.2.2, `system_auth` became a keyspace whose replication strategy and replication factor you can change, so it'd make a difference if you upgraded, but that's not really your problem.

In the end, what you probably want to be doing is describing the ring for one of your *own* keyspaces, since that's where the replication in your cluster probably matters most to you.